# Tracking data not sent back to sales cloud from Journey Builder Using Sales and Service Cloud events and activities?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Tracking data not sent back to sales cloud from Journey Builder Using Sales and Service Cloud events and activities. My journey starts whenever campaign member is updated, I get mails but the tracking data for this mail is not available.
I have latest version of connector installed.
Where is this tracking data available in sales cloud?

Can any one help me with some inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracking data would be available as Individual Email results and individual Link details in Salesforce. Check the below if the tracking data is not visible:

1. Check if you have added Individual Email results as a related list
   in Lead/Contacts object
2. If the mail send is from Marketing cloud, check if the subscriber key is Lead/Contact id
3. In the Marketing cloud connect configuration in salesforce, check the Tracking frequency. Tracking data would be updated only as per the tracking frequency.
4. If the mail send is from Marketing cloud, make sure you check the box to send the tracking data to salsforce.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, 
I have verified all the steps mentioned above by you. This all are being configured as it should be. But still i am not able to get the tracking send data in individual sends.

Thanks,Kalpesh

Comment: are you using multi org setup?

Comment: No I have multiple bussiness units but we are not using multi org setup

Comment: I'm facing same issue. All described steps I already followed but the tracking isn't returning to SalesCloud... I read that the Data Extension should be a Salesforce DE. But Salesforce DE isn't available on Journey Builder. So I don't know how to act! Can you help me?

Comment: @KalpeshGandhi have you been able to solve this?